# Else branch isn't executed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code, but the `else` branch doesn't work

```
def main():
   while True:
        username = input ("Enter Username: ")
        password = input ("Enter Password: ")

   if username == 'Filip' and password == 'XD' or "Miroslav" and "plusko12":
            import time
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("Login successful!")
            logged()
   else:
      print("STOP")


def logged():
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Welcome to the Server")
    #Booting now
    print("Booting will begin shortly")
    import time
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Starting.................0%")
    # ... and there's more stuff in here
    quit(0)

main()
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in this context?  By the way, try `if (username == 'Filip' and password == 'XD') or (username == "Miroslav" and password == "plusko12"):`

Comment: Did you mean `and password in {'XD', "Miroslav", "plusko12"}`?

Comment: I think the indentation is also incorrect, I suspect the `if` should be inside the `while`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that "don't work":

```
while True:
    username = input ("Enter Username: ")
    password = input ("Enter Password: ")
```

will never exit because there's no stop condition.

Then the next `if`:

```
if username == 'Filip' and password == 'XD' or "Miroslav" and "plusko12":
```

will always evaluate to True because any not empty string is True and it's evaluated like this:

```
if (username == 'Filip' and password == 'XD') or ("Miroslav" and "plusko12")
#                                                |---this is always True---|
```

and because one of the `or` operands is always True it will always enter the branch.

Also a more general hint: If you `import time` at the top without indentation you don't need to constantly re`import` it (most of them are unnecessary as is).